# Remove the last 3 symbol of the number integer in Delphi

Tags: delphi, integer, rounding

I'd like to round this number (12345678) to (12345000) in Delphi. How can i do that? I search a lot but I didn't find anything. (The similar code in SQL is Round(x,-3,1)). also I don't know how to use ( GetRoundMode ) .
Thanks :)

Comment: Delphi also  has `RoundTo(value, digits)` function, it works the same as in SQL, but returns double value

Comment: actually, round(12345678, -3) gives 1234*6* not 12345. So what do you want, usual round or `RoundUP` or `roundDown`?, answers below round value to smaller value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function can be implemented like this:

```
function RoundDownToThousand(Value: Cardinal): Cardinal;
begin
  Result := (Value div 1000)*1000;
end;
```

Note that I used an unsigned type to avoid having to predict what behaviour you want for negative values. If you do want to support negative values, use `Integer`, and modify the code to give your desired behaviour.

---

To counter @HeartWare's assertion that his code is faster, I offer the following program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Diagnostics;

function RoundDownToThousandModSub(Value: Cardinal): Cardinal;
begin
  Result := Value - Value mod 1000;
end;

function RoundDownToThousandDivMul(Value: Cardinal): Cardinal;
begin
  Result := (Value div 1000)*1000;
end;

var
  i: Cardinal;
  Stopwatch: TStopwatch;

begin
  Stopwatch := TStopwatch.StartNew;
  for i := 0 to 1000000000 do
    RoundDownToThousandModSub(i);
  Writeln('RoundDownToThousandModSub: '+IntToStr(Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds));

  Stopwatch := TStopwatch.StartNew;
  for i := 0 to 1000000000 do
    RoundDownToThousandDivMul(i);
  Writeln('RoundDownToThousandDivMul: '+IntToStr(Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds));

  Readln;
end.
```

I ran this on Win7 x64 on a E5530 processor, compiled with XE3, both 32 and 64 bit, using the default console project template with RELEASE build settings.

**32 bit results**

```
RoundDownToThousandModSub: 5251
RoundDownToThousandDivMul: 5214
```

**64 bit results**

```
RoundDownToThousandModSub: 5317
RoundDownToThousandDivMul: 5297
```

So pick the version that you feel reads better. Never ever take a performance decision without measuring. You will frequently discover that your intuition on performance is wrong.

Comment: +1. While I personally prefer the readability of the mod version, this works as well, and the meaningless performance difference is...well, meaningless. Nice to see the benchmarks, too - I'd add an additional vote for that extra effort if I could.

Answer (score 5):

A faster version (not that it'll matter much) is this:

```
function RoundDownToThousand(Value: Cardinal): Cardinal;
begin
  Result := Value - Value mod 1000
end;
```

This will only incur a single "expensive" operation (the mod operator) in contrast to the 2 (div and multiplication) of the one provided by David.

However, the effective speed gain is probably negligible.

EDIT: Like I said, the speed gain is negligible according to both David's and my own tests, and is largely dependent on what other things your PC is doing at the time. I even tried an optimized 32-bit assembler version of my routine (that ended up looking almost identical to the one that Delphi provided from the PASCAL source, but with a few tweaks) and that one came out a few ms faster most of the time, but in some cases very much slower than the other ones - again implying that the timing will be much dependent on what other things your PC is doing.

As Ken noted, it was bad form to assume that it was faster - from the looks of the PASCAL code it certainly would appear that it *should* be faster (only one "expensive" operation), but like David said, one shouldn't always take things for granted. The need to push/pop a general purpose register slowed it down enough to make it the same as the other function.

EDIT^2: If I coded the optimized 32-bit assembler routine so that it didn't push/pop the 32-bit register it needed (I checked the generated code to see which register I could use that normally *should* have been preserved), the code (in most cases, but not all) executed faster than both of the PASCAL ones, heavily implying that it was indeed the push/pop that caused the slowdown of the simpler looking PASCAL routine...

But like Ken, I would go for this one - because it's the way I "think" the solution, ie. I want to elimimate (subtract) the last three digits of the number (which I get by calculating a MOD 1000). David's function (IMO) seems "wrong" and too complicated when I think of the solution the way I envision it, but that may just be the way people wrap their minds around a logical problem to visualize the solution...

Comment: In what sense is that version faster? My timings suggest there is no difference. Can you please show your benchmark program that showed a performance difference, and also let us know which processor you used for your benchmarking.

Comment: While this would be my preferred solution, I'm not upvoting (not downvoting either, of course) because of the unproven claim it's "faster". I wouldn't object to "An alternative version" or "An alternate solution", but "it's faster" without any proof that it is so or that performance is an issue at all (AKA "optimization simply for the sake of optimization") is meaningless.

Comment: I have run some tests using David's code, and on my Delphi 2007, it's touch and go whether or not the one version or the other is faster. In most cases, they differ only by a few milliseconds (either way), but in some cases it is around 100 ms difference (again either way), so it is largely dependent on what else the computer is doing at the time (mine was copying large files across the network at the same time). For instance, the last one I just ran had these values (I doubled the iterations to get a larger sample): RoundDownToThousandModSub:9469 RoundDownToThousandDivMul:10141

Comment: Perhaps you'll do some benchmarking in future before making claims about performance!  ;-)